# Mod_spnego.co Apache 2.4 issue

Tags: apache, kerberos

We have an old application running on Apache 2.2 which is using Kerberos for user authentification.
But right now we have to swap to Apache 2.4.
Do you know if there is any mod_spnego.co package for Apache 2.4 that I can use?
I was Googling for a while but I only found something about recompiling the package (but I don't have any C programming skills).

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: What OS are you running this on -- Windows or Linux-like?

Comment: Hello, Windows server 2012.